# Vagrant and wordpress not working

Tags: css, wordpress, vagrant

Recently I have started using vagrant for Wordpress development.

The installation process and everything else went well. But when i try to access the page I get to see this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJQCF.png)

It also loads really slow. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you inspected in your browser and checked the network tab? Where does it try to load the assets from?

Comment: Yes sir. http://i.imgur.com/vxr3xDv.png

Comment: another weird thing is, i can access the file through the ip adress only. and not the .dev domain name

Comment: Then, that's your problem. If the name doesn't resolve, none of these assets will ever be dowloaded. Have you ever added `salesacademie.dev` to your `hosts` file?

Comment: I havent. And i dont know how to be honest. I'm kinda new to all this.

Comment: It worked, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to resolve `salesacademie.dev`, you will need to [add the name to your hosts file](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/modify-your-hosts-file/). The line you need should look something like

```
salesacademie.dev  127.0.0.1
```

With that change, you should be able to download the assets (and the site) using that name assuming that vagrant's port forward is for port 80 (the standard http port).

Alternatively, you can reconfigure your Wordpress to not use the name `salesacademie.dev` but 127.0.0.1 instead. Then, you don;t need to edit your hosts file. However, you will not be able to run several websites concurrently on your vagrant server then.